# SQL Server Stored Procedure plan error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an application running on ASP.Net using C#. The database is SQL Server 2008 R2. The asp.net application also heavily uses jQuery and AJAX.

We have a page that has a few dropdowns which are populated using jQuery AJAX calls. The cache parameter in AJAX calls has been set to "false". The AJAX calls target a Page-based WebMethod (i.e. PageMethod) that in-turn calls a Stored Procedure. This Stored Procedure returns a dataset which is converted to JSON output and returned back to AJAX call.

Recently, we have started facing a weird issue, where the Stored Procedures executed on the AJAX calls are throwing errors like "Cannot convert 'undefined' to int". We have debugged the entire logic on production and there is no value like 'undefined' that is being passed as a parameter to the Stored Procedure. We also started Sql Profiler and there also the parameters being passed is valid.

Additionally, if we execute the Stored Procedure with the parameters displayed in the Sql Profiler, it executes successfully without any error. At this point the only "fix" that we have discovered is to open the stored procedure in SSMS and execute the stored procedure script generated as is (without any changes to the script). Once this alter script is executed, the Stored Procedure starts to return values correctly. This works for a few days / weeks and then again we have the same problem.

Does anyone have any idea why does this happen? Could this be a problem with SQL Stored Procedure execution plan cache?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, the "undefined" is common error. as you said executing SP from ssms is fine. I think after executing you may get the result in you ajax , here your jquery may not process that result. Create a simple test stored procedure and call that from your ajax. we will came to know  whether it hits or not. Also please make sure connectivity of sql and connection timeout, Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. We had debugged the code and the error is not getting thrown at jquery. It is actually throwing an SqlException when Stored Procedure is called from .Net code. The error message "Cannot convert 'undefined' to int" is actually displayed in the ErrorMessage of the SqlException. Additionally this issue is not occurring with all stored procedures. At this point there are only 3 stored procs that behave this way. One more point to note is that after we re-run the stored proc script, the issue is resolved for a few weeks. I can confirm there is no connectivity issue.

Comment: No Idea Hope your issue resolved soon! And post how you resolved that may helpful for someone. Thanks!